# Is it expected behavior for a RETURNING clause to result in no exception for a constraint violation?

Tags: php, mariadb

This is a follow-up question to this poorly written [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444235/can-mysqli-execute-ever-return-a-0-to-php) of mine from the other day.

At the close of all those comments, I thought the answer was that if I used the mysqli exceptions via `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` rather than attempting to process the return values of every statement, which requires `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);`, my problem would be solved.  However, I was wrong.

Regardless of whether return values or exceptions are employed to catch sql errors in PHP, the `RETURNING` clause results in a `$stmt->execute()` return value of `true` and no `1062` exception.

A working example of the following test code aggregated from the previous question is provided [here](https://phpize.online/sql/mariadb/undefined/php/php81/3df036e7d9a22a501d824b424070a887/).

The question, now, is why does the `RETURNING` clause result in "success" rather than first failing due to constraint violation?  Is this expected behavior?  Is it "bad" practice to use a `RETURNING` clause in an `INSERT INTO` statement?

If the same statements are executed from the CLI, both with and without `RETURNING` fail with 1062; as opposed to with `RETURNING` resulting in a `NULL` return value.

Thank you.

```
$mysqli->query("create table t (id int primary key unique, stat tinyint default 1)");

// First two blocks use default of: 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
echo "mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);\n";

// Without RETURNING clause.
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("insert into t (id) values(?)");
$id = 3;
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$id = 3;
try {
$stmt->execute();
echo "This doesn't execute;\n";
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() === 1062) {
        echo "Without RETURNING: Duplicate id $id\n";
    } else {
        throw $e; // in case there is any other error
    }
}
$stmt->close();

// With RETURNING clause.
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into t (id) values(?) RETURNING id");
$id = 3;
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$id = 3;
try {
$stmt->execute();
echo "With RETURNING: No exception reported.\n";
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() === 1062) {
        echo "Duplicate id $id\n";
    } else {
        throw $e; // in case there is any other error
    }
}
$stmt->close();

// Next two blocks use:
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
echo "\nmysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);\n";

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("insert into t (id) values(?)");
$id = 3;
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
echo "Without RETURNING: ";
var_dump($stmt->execute());
$stmt->close();

// With RETURNING clause.
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("insert into t (id) values(?) RETURNING id;");
$id = 3;
$stmt->bind_param('i',$i);
echo "With RETURNING: ";
var_dump($stmt->execute());
```

Results:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
Without RETURNING: Duplicate id 3
With RETURNING: No exception reported.

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
Without RETURNING: bool(false)
With RETURNING: bool(true)
```

Comment: There is no `RETURNING` in MySQL, so I'm very curious to know where you even picked this up.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I forgot it's hidden in a comment.  I'm using LAMP on Manjaro Linux and it uses MariaDB.  I'm just a hack and have been messing with SQLite and MariaDB; so I might be misusing some terms. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/ is where I found it.

Comment: MariaDB is not MySQL. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, and they still have quite a bit of code in common, but both products have been steadily adding features since then, not all of which are supported in the other product. Folks really need to stop thinking of MariaDB as compatible with MySQL except barely at the protocol level.

Comment: @Gary then I strongly recommend not using mysqli. Use PDO instead.

Comment: I had a look on the mariadb command line interface and it seemed consistent between `INSERT` and `INSERT .. RETURNING`. Which PHP version? I can't see anything in [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net). Much better question BTW, much appreciated.

Comment: @danblack PHP version 8.1.6-1. Thanks.